# Approximate relation between $k$ in $Y(t)=1-\exp(-kt)$ and $R=\frac{X(1-Y)}{Y(1-X)}$ where $d X/dt=15(Y-X)$ with $X(0)=0$?

Tags: approximation

How to get the approximation
$$ \frac{15}{k}\approx\frac{4R}{(1-R)^2} $$
given that
$$  \frac{15}{k}=\frac{X(1-X)}{Y(Y-X)} $$
and
$$  R=\frac{X(1-Y)}{Y(1-X)} $$
where $k$ and $R$ are constants, and $Y(t)=1-\exp(-kt)$ with $t>0$.

I was stuck with this approximation when I was studying the theory of chromatography - a series of research papers wrote by E. Glueckauf. One can check the origin [here](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/1955/TF/TF9555101540#!divAbstract).

$R$ is defined as the distribution factor of an adsorption isotherm $Y=f(X)$. For Langmuir isotherms $R$ is a constant as shown before. According to the constant pattern condition which suggests $\bar Y=X$ and by taking the linear diffusion equation which gives $d \bar Y/dt=15(Y-\bar Y)$, the author finally obtained this approximate relation. $\bar Y$ is the actual uptake at concentration $X$. $\bar Y(0)=0$. $Y$ is the equilibrium uptake at concentration $X$. Concentration $X$ varies with time $t$.

But he didn't demonstrate the derivation process, which obsessed me for quite a while. What the author was trying to do is to link the output shape characterized by $k$ to the input shape characterized by $R$. I hope someone could help disperse the mist around me.

---

My thought is as below:

Suppose $k=4\pi^2$, one can give a plot of $Y$ against $X$:
[image]

This isotherm $Y=f(X)$ should be characterized by the Langmuir equation:
$$Y=\frac{X}{R+(1-R)X}$$
So by fitting the isotherm, $R$ can be obtained. Thus an input $k$ gives an output $R$. $R$ is highly related to $k$. By plenty of calculations, one will obtain a plot of $k$ against $R$. That plot may be characterized by
$$ k \approx \frac{15(1-R)^2}{4R}$$
as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide some context here, such as where this problem comes from and what your own thoughts on the matter are?

Comment: What's the regime of the approximation? $kt \gg 1$?

Comment: @David Quinn: I've updated my question. Hope I've made it clear enough.

Comment: @lan: I wouldn't take that regime to get the approximation. See my updated description about this question.

Comment: That doesn't actually look like a very good estimate.

Comment: @lan: Yeah, which makes me wonder how the author got this approximation.